# Wifi network selection window won't close

Tags: macos, network, wifi, high-sierra, bug

The network selection window that opens when you click the WIFI icon >> Join Other Network >> Show Networks, is stuck open. Clicking "Cancel" doesn't close it.

How could I fix this without restarting my mac? What process is responsible for that window? Can I (force) quit that process? Does it automatically restart, or do I have to manually restart it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [UIElementInspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/UIElementInspector.zip) (more info [here](https://superuser.com/a/346984/33005)) to find out a lot of behind-the-scenes stuff for individual windows or other elements of the macOS user interface.

This shows that the dialog you are referring to is part of *SystemUIServer*. You can simply *Quit* (no need to *Force Quit*) the *SystemUIServer* process using *Activity Monitor.app* and it will automatically restart thanks to *launchd*.

*SystemUIServer* is responsible for the right side of the menu bar (menu extras/menulings) and a few other things. See [this archived page for more info](https://web.archive.org/web/20170516090624/http://guides.macrumors.com/SystemUIServer).

[image]